# How to make Quarto (.qmd) files appear like R markdown files (.rmd) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, r-markdown, quarto

I am trying to apply a style/color theme for .qmd files, so that they appear like .rmd files in VS code. I have been able to change the style/color for .qmd files by entering the following code the settings.json file.

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.qmd": "rmd"
},
```

This does work for updating the theme of the .qmd file to look like R markdown (rmd) files. However, when rendering a PDF I get the following error:

> ==> rmarkdown::render(),
> encoding = 'UTF-8') Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required
> and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
>
> Execution halted
>
> [VSC-R] filename.qmd process exited with exit code 1 [VSC-R]
> terminating R process

I believe this is because Quarto can only render a .qmd file, and file.associations changes it to .rmd? Thoughts on solutions? Thanks in advance!

.rmd example

[image]

.qmd example

[image]